# How is this hex checksum calculated?

Tags: hex, checksum, data-integrity

I am currently doing some work interfacing with an embedded system. Within this system there are a series of hexadecimal configuration values, and a checksum at the end.

The four values are as follows:

- 0A346149
- 0A346169
- 0A3460C4
- 0A346189

The 'checksum' required is **047A0000**

The very limited documentation I have for this suggests that the checksum is a byte addition of the four values, however I cannot replicate this.

How has this checksum been calculated, and can you work through it step-by-step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the sum of all of the individual bytes taken one byte at a time.

```py
>>> (0x0A + 0x34 + 0x61 + 0x49 + 
     0x0A + 0x34 + 0x61 + 0x69 + 
     0x0A + 0x34 + 0x60 + 0xC4 + 
     0x0A + 0x34 + 0x61 + 0x89)
1146
>>> 0x047a
1146
```

(It's possible that it's just a 16-bit checksum and the `0000` bytes are not a part of it. If they are, `047A0000` is an unusual byte arrangement for `0x47a`—it's neither big nor little endian.)

Comment: This system is all about unusal byte arrangement, likely due to its age. I think you're probably right about the 16 bit checksum - IIRC the data bus in this system was 16 bits wide. Thanks for the quick response.